# AJAX Post request with Razor Pages parameter class

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I'm trying to implement a simple ajax with razor pages, but the parameter is not transmitted.

Here is the ajax

```
document.querySelector("#btnEditTeamSave").addEventListener("click", function editTeamSubmit(event) { 
    
    event.preventDefault();
    var theTeam = { Id:$('#btnEditTeamSave').val(), Name: $('#EditTeamName').val(), Description: $('#EditTeamDescription').val(), MachineId: $('#EditTeamMachine').val(),Active: $('#EditTeamActive').val(), Color: $('#EditTeamColorPicker').val()  };
    //JSON.stringify(theTeam)

       console.log(JSON.stringify(theTeam));
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?handler=Team",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: JSON.stringify(theTeam),
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken:
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
  },false)
```

And here is the model

```
   public class TeamShort
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? MachineId { get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }
        public string? Color { get; set; }
    }

public IActionResult OnPostTeam([FromBody]TeamShort theTeam)
{


    return new JsonResult("succes"); 
}
```

But the model theTeam is empty

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwFx0.png

This is the log from the console with theTeam

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPpFe.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKoyC.png

The issue was the type of attributes from the class.

The active attribute has the value "on", and this value cannot be converted into "true"

Comment: good job sir : ) and pls forgive my late reply since I also tried to reproduce the issue. what you did is right

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, when I using `var theTeam = {Id: "1", Name: "name1", Description: "desc", MachineId: "MachineId",Active: "false", Color: "red"};` as the parameter, it will lead reproduce the issue.

When I use `var theTeam = {Id: "1", Name: "name1", Description: "desc", MachineId: "MachineId",Active: false, Color: "red"};` it worked for me.

The issue may relate to the model type `public bool? Active { get; set; }`.

So in my idea, when we want to send ajax request in Razor Pages, we may choose to write request like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://localhost:7036",
    data: {
        Id:1,
        Name:"name1",
        Description: "desc",
        MachineId:"MachineId",
        Active:false,
        Color:"red"
    },
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    success:function(res){
        console.info(res);
    }
})

//don't need [FromBody] here
public IActionResult OnPost(TeamShort team)
{
    return new JsonResult("succes");
}
```